# how to extract contour using freeman chain code using matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, pattern-recognition

I work in my project on the problem of writer recognition from handwritten Arabic documents.

to identify the writer, I used a database image, 
 My problem is how to extract features from these images. I'm new in matlab and I do not have much knowledge in image processing.

please help me, I need to extract the contour from image and then encode it using freeman chain codes.

[The following link contains freeman code in matlab but I do not know how to use it.](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29518-freeman-chain-code/content/chaincode.m)

I welcome your suggestion and thank you in advance

Comment: Can you give an example image? Do you have the contour already?

Comment: Since this question is closed I'll post a link to code that works here: https://github.com/maximilianallan/mk_chain/blob/master/mk_chain.m

Call chaincode on the output chain

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `imcontour` function.

For instance, if you load this sample image

[image: Sample image]

```
Img = imread('test.png');
```

You can get the contour with the command:

```
C = imcontour(Img, 1);
```

[image: Result contour]

Then you can use the freeman function you cite with C as the first input.

Comment: I tryed but I got error

Comment: @ Crasy the error is `Error using chaincode (line 78)
  Curve isn't 8-connected in elements:
  idx -> 1


  Error in main (line 12)
  [cc] = chaincode(C);`

Comment: getting same error

Answer (score 1):

Another example could be to use [`bwperim`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwperim.html).  This essentially takes a look at all of the distinct binary objects in an image and extracts the perimeter of each object.  This only works for objects that are white, and so using @Crazy rat's example, we can thus do:

```
im = ~im2bw(imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9BZl.png'));
out = ~bwperim(im);
```

The above will read in the image and convert it into binary / `logical`.  Next, we need to **invert** the image so that the object / text is white while the background is black.  After, call `bwperim` so that you extract the perimeter of the objects, and then to convert back so that the object text is black, we re-invert.

The output I get is:

[image]

The distinct advantage with `bwperim` over `imcontour` is that `bwperim` provides the actual output image whereas `imcontour` only draws a figure for you.  You can certainly extract the image data from the figure, like using the `h = gcf; out = h.cdata;` idiom, but this will include some of the figure background in the result.  I suspect you would like the actual raw image instead, and so I would recommend using `bwperim`.

## How do we use this with the Freeman code you linked?

If you look at the source code, it takes in two inputs:

1. `b`, which is a `N x 2` matrix of coordinates that determine the boundary of the shape you want to encode
2. `unwrap` - An optional parameter

If you want to use the function that you have linked us to, simply extract the row and column coordinates of those pixels that are along the boundary of your image.  As such, this is another limitation of `imcontour`, as you won't be able to determine these locations without the raw contour image itself.  Therefore, all you really have to do is:

```
[y,x] = find(out == 0);
cc = chaincode([y x]);
```

Comment: @ rayryeng I was tryed this code but i got error

Comment: @sahar - And what mystical error would this be?  I'm not a mind reader.  Be more specific.

Comment: Error in main (line 10)
cc = chaincode([y x]);

Comment: @sahar - What is the **full error**?  I will stop answering you until then.

Comment: @ rayryeng  Error in main (line 10)
cc = chaincode([y x]);

Comment: @sahar - Yeah sorry. I'm not helping you anymore.  Good luck!

Comment: the full error is `idx -> 29107
 idx -> 29113
 idx -> 29114
 idx -> 29116
 idx -> 29117
 idx -> 29118
 idx -> 29119
 idx -> 29120
 idx -> 29121
 idx -> 29122
 idx -> 29123
 idx -> 29129
 idx -> 29130
 idx -> 29133
 idx -> 29134
 idx -> 29137
 idx -> 29138
 idx -> 29139
 idx -> 29140
 idx -> 29141
 idx -> 29142
 idx -> 29143
 idx -> 29146`                                                                                                 Error in main (line 10) cc = chaincode([y x]);

Comment: @ rayryeng please help me to find solution

Comment: I think that a very important detail missing from this answer is the content of the `chaincode` which is not a Matlab function. I'm guessing it's the [Freeman Chain Code](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29518-freeman-chain-code) function on Mathworks File Exchange

Comment: @carandraug the OP linked to this code on MATLAB FEX above in the question. I assumed the OP already downloaded it.

Comment: ah yes. I see his link on the question now. Makes sense.

Comment: @carandraug I'll admit that I had to stare at the post for a minute or two. I answered this question so long ago that I didn't remember answering in the context of already downloading the code from FEX. I'll edit the post to make this link clear.